# Windows: command after the for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, echo

Sorry,

I don't seem to find answer to my simple question.

I find tons of examples for for loops but then none of them report a command executed after the loop.

In my case I want to remove the echo feature and then re-enable it when the foor loop has terminated.

```
@echo off & for /F "tokens=*" %A in (linuxserver.txt) do ( echo %A )
```

If I put an ampersand before the command @echo on it's interpreted as being part of the inner command set, if I don't put anything or just a semicolon then I get "@echo was unexpected at this time."

```
@echo off&for /F "tokens=*" %A in (linuxserver.txt) do ( echo %A ) @echo on
```

I thought the brackets would delimit the inner commands of the loop.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0):

Loop command syntax is:

```
FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ('command_to_process') DO command
```

or

```
FOR /F ["options"] %parameter IN ('command_to_process') DO command
```

options "tokens=*" will cause all items on each line to be processed
For parameter, in a batch file use %%A (on the command line %A)

If linuxserver.txt has the following entries:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Then output of your command used

```
command: for /F "tokens=*" %A in ('type linuxserver.txt') do ( echo %A )
```

output:

```
(echo tokens=aaa  )
tokens=aaa
(echo tokens=bbb  )
tokens=bbb
(echo ccc  )
ccc
```

With echo off and then back to on should be (if you use a batch file) as:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('type linuxserver.txt') do ( echo %%A )
@echo on
```

In single line as command, 
you could use at most the following:

```
@echo off & for /F "tokens=*" %A in ('type linuxserver.txt') do (echo %A)
```

And as a separate line run:

```
echo on
```

Comment: Thanks Debasish Jana,

the issue is right the

"And as a separate line run:

echo on"

I'm used to oneliners in Linux and hence on the same command line I'd like to have all the commands. Mind you that echo on is just an example. I may have something else. Maybe shall we tune the usage of  the switch tokens (which I didn't think of at the beginning?)

Comment: I'm used to oneliners in Linux and hence on the same command line I'd like to have all the commands. Mind you that echo on is just an example. I may have something else. Maybe shall we tune the usage of  the switch tokens (which I didn't think of at the beginning) ?